# JQuery set css not consistently running

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

This is my ajax function that gets a link from my controller and sets a background image for an element in my page.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "@Url.Action("View", "TenantBackgroundAccess", new {area="Configuration" })?TenantId=" + tenantId,
    success: function (result) {
        if (result != null) {
            $('#tenant-menu-container').css('background', 'linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5),rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)), url(' + result.Link + ') ');
            $('#tenant-menu-container').css('background-size', 'cover');
            $('#tenant-menu-container').css('background-repeat', 'no-repeat');
        }
    },
    complete: function (result) {
        if (result != null && result.status == 200) {
            $('#tenant-menu-container').css('background', 'linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5),rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)), url(' + result.responseJSON.Link + ') ');
            $('#tenant-menu-container').css('background-size', 'cover');
            $('#tenant-menu-container').css('background-repeat', 'no-repeat');
        }
    },
    error: function (result) {
        console.log(result);
    }
});
```

The issue is that maybe 50% of the time, I get a result but no image is applied to my background. If I reload the page, then maybe the image will appear.

Am I doing something wrong? The reason I have success and complete is to try to ensure that the image is loaded. However, this doesn't fix the issue.

Comment: Have you logged `result` to see what's happening when it *doesn't* work?

Comment: Yeah, I did a console log and the result appeared as per normal

Comment: So even when the images *aren't* loading, the `result` is working as expected, and there are no errors in the console anywhere?

Comment: No errors to the console. Its just that the css is not being applied

Comment: Have you added console.log flags to each condition to see how they're firing?

Comment: Yes I have. The results output as per normal. No error appears.

Comment: I actually put the console.log outside of the if statement to capture the whole thing. It still appears as per normal. No idea why setting the css fails sometimes.

Comment: I think I discovered the issue. There is another function that sets a background color before the image is set. I put an !important there so maybe thats why its overwriting this? not sure.